# to say not even a word vs not to say even a word

Tags: meaning, verbs, adverb-placement

Are there any differences in meaning between the following sentences? Are they equally usual?

> A. He said not even a word.
>
> B. He did not say even a word.
>
> C. He did not even say a word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand what you mean by "equally usual"; I don't think A and B are common usage. Out of the three, sentence C is the most idiomatic to me. When it comes to *meaning*, all three are *attempting* to say the same thing - *He did not say a word*. Only C gets it across correctly.

All of the following

> "He did not even say a word", "He did not even look at me", "He did not even reply to my text message"

are more common constructions in comparison to the constructions of A and B.

I am having difficulty in finding a situation where B would be more appropriate than C.

*"Even"* is an adverb here. According to Cambridge, *"even"* *is used to show that something is surprising, unusual, unexpected, or extreme*.

Cambridge says:

> When "even" refers to a whole clause or sentence, we **usually** put it in the normal mid position for adverbs, **between the subject and the main verb**, **after the modal verb or [after the] first auxiliary verb, or after be as a main verb.**

See *[Even](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/even)*.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. A and B are equally usual = A is as usual as B

Comment: @AlanEvangelista Ahhh I see. Usually, we ask  "Are they equivalent? Are they interchangeable? Are they synonymous? Are they equally common in usage?" I am just not familiar with "Are they equally usual?", but it is not wrong. Sorry about that.